# Question about subtracting mean on train/valid/test set

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, data-preprocessing

I'm doing data preprocessing and going to build a Convonets on my data after.

My question is: 
Say I have a total data sets with 100 images, I was calculating mean for each one of the 100 images and then subtract it from each of the images, then split this into train and validation set, and I do the same steps to process on a given test set, but it seems like this is not a correct way doing it according to this link:http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#datapre

> > "**Common pitfall**. An important point to make about the preprocessing is that any preprocessing statistics (e.g. the data mean) must only be computed on the training data, and then applied to the validation / test data. E.g. computing the mean and subtracting it from every image across the entire dataset and then splitting the data into train/val/test splits would be a mistake. Instead, the mean must be computed only over the training data and then subtracted equally from all splits (train/val/test)."

I'm guessing what the author is saying is that, do not compute mean and subtract it within each image but compute the mean of the total image set(i.e. (image1 + ... + image100)/100) and subtract the mean to each of the image.

I don't quite understand can anyone explain? and also possibly explain why what I was doing is wrong(if it is wrong indeed).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's assume you have 100 images in total; 90 are training data and 10 are test data.

The authors correctly asserts that using the whole 100 image sample to compute the sample mean $\hat{\mu}$ is wrong. That is because in this case you would have information leakage. Information from your "out-of-sample" elements would be move to your training set. In particular for the estimation of $\hat{\mu}$ , if you use 100 instead of 90 images you allow your training set to have a more informed mean than it should have too. As a result your training error would be potentially lower than it should be.

The estimated $\hat{\mu}$ is common throughout the training/validation/testing procedure. The same $\hat{\mu}$ is to be use to centre all your data. (I mention this later because I have the slight impression you use the mean of each separate image to centre that image.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense. And yes, I am calculating the mean for each images, so the estimated $\hat{\mu}$ should actually be calculated by the whole 90 training images instead of on each single image? Any reason why? Can't I centring each of the individual image in the 90 training set?

Comment: The estimate $\hat{\mu}$ should be an image itself. If you centre each individually the centring you do does not control for any overall trend in the whole sample.

Comment: @usεr11852  Why would having more informed mean harm our model? This would not cause the information of "out-of-sample response variable",in any way interfere in our training, right? So why would the train error be low?

Comment: Valid information will never "harm a model"; after deciding which model to use (based on some resampling/hold-out scheme) we will train the final model on *all data*. Nevertheless when training if we estimate $\hat{\mu}$ using the whole dataset, this additional information will be reflecting unrealistic good insights. This can lead to lower test-errors than expected exactly because we know something about out tests data that we would not otherwise be able to use during training. (*Example*: Say we develop a physical activity model. Our data include teenagers, adults and elderly and (cont.)

Comment: ... by some fluke, all the elderly people end up in the test-set. If we calculate the mean-age in our training-set only, we will obviously get a lower mean-age than what our whole sample has. Using this obviously biased mean-age will probably deteriorate the model's `A` performance if `A` does not generalise well to different ages. If we calculate the mean-age in the whole dataset we will get a more representative mean-age. If we now use this unbiased mean-age in the model `A` we will probably get better performance than before despite `A` not generalising well to different ages.)

Comment: (Yes, the example is a bit hammy and age would be some obvious to check but in many application our insights are much more limited as with age here.)